# Updating a form from a partial view from JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a freshman in ASP MVC3 and very very very freshman in JQuery

I'm working on an ordering process for some items, how it's working currently is when the user clicks on the 'Create Order' link,they are taken to a list of the items to be ordered (formatted using a table) and after clicking on an item, a form loads containing details of the selected item, at this point the user can add additional information on the form before creating the order.

I would like to simplify this process by having the user work from one view. I would like this view to have the above mentioned form and a partial of the item list mentioned above, so that when the user selects an item on the partial, the form is loaded with the item details without opening a new page.

QUESTION is, how do I load up the form with the selected item in the partial view? I'm stuck at the JQuery part, no idea how this script will look like.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you could take a look at [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Maybe even read some [tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc) or watch a [couple of videos](http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight) and learn how it could integrate with ASP.NET MVC could be useful for your current and future projects. Of course you shouldn't hesitate to come back to Stack Overflow once you have a specific question to ask. You could show your efforts and code, explain the difficulties you have encountered and we would have a common base for discussion.

Comment: Hello Darin I did do some research and was able to make progress on the JQuery. I'm able to populate form controls from a list of items in a partial view (The form and the partial view are on the same page) what I want to do now is be able to update sections of the form by selecting an item from the list without clearing the whole form (I'm filling parts of the form manually and don't wants those parts to clear when I change the item selection on the list). Yes I'll do more research on how to go about this. Thanks though, if I hit the rock I'll post the code and ask for assistance.